# Python: определить значение какого типа записано в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы, преобразование-типов

Есть строка в которой записано целое число, число с плавающей точкой или просто строка (до кучи можно придумать еще несколько типов, типа даты).

Подскажите - определить это можно только перебором в лоб по типу:

```
text = "13.6"

type = 'unknown'

try:
    value = int(text)
    type = 'int number'
except:
    try:
        value = float(text)
        type = 'float number'
    except:
        type = 'string'
```

или есть какие-то библиотечные более изящные способы? :)

Comment: Почитайте про isinstance

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261141/determine-type-of-value-from-a-string-in-python.

Comment: И что по вашему `isinstance('123', int)` должно  показать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как упомянул @Сергей Кох в комментариях, вы можете использовать [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Вот код, который может помочь вам:

```py
from ast import literal_eval


def get_type(var_str: str):
    try: # Если не обрабатывается - значит, это строка
        var_str = literal_eval(var_str)
        var_type = type(var_str)
    except ValueError:
        var_type = str
    return str(var_type)


print(get_type("aAaaA"))
# <class 'str'>

print(get_type("454545"))
# <class 'int'>

print(get_type("1.12"))
# <class 'float'>
```

В случае, если вы хотите добавить, например, дату / время, вам придётся использовать регулярные выражения. Вы можете почитать о них в [официальной документации модуля `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: А если обрабатывается то это ещё и список, кортеж, словарь, булево значение и ещё много чего.